# Opencv headers different version and libraries different version: ubuntu

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, caffe

I am new to Ubuntu and OpenCV. Apologies for my amateurishness.

I think I messed up OpenCV installation.

I had installed OpenCV 2.4 months back. The installation was successful (built openCV from source using CMake)

Couple of days back I had also installed OpenCV 3.0 using the same procedure.
The problem began when one of my code gave a segmentation fault for seemingly no reason. On suggestion by a friend on Caffe Neural Network issues forum (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3416), it seems that I am compiling with 3.0 headers but linking against the 2.4 libraries.

I checked /usr/local/include. It has the standard openCv header files ( I didn't understand what 'compiling with 3.0 header means' )

In /usr/local/lib I have OpenCV 3.0 libraries ( no 2.4.8 at all).

Now compilation was successful, but when I try to run it, I get the following error.

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x00007ffff76c49bc in cv::merge(cv::_InputArray const&,       
 cv::_OutputArray     const&) ()
 from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4
```

Just to add

"pkg-config --modversion opencv"
3.0.0

whereas dpkg -l | grep libopencv
gave out

i libopencv-calib3d-dev:amd64 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 amd64 development files for libopencv-calib3d
ii libopencv-calib3d2.4:amd64 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 amd64 computer vision Camera Calibration library
ii libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 amd64 development files for libopencv-contrib
.......

q.1> why does my code link to libopencv_core.so.2.4 instead of 3.0. I have checked in /usr/local/lib and did not see a single 2.4 library. I have tried manually defining links to header files and libraries in CMake but still same result.

q.2> Do OpenCV headers have a version number? I don't understand how they are called '2.4 headers'. I have checked the source code but did not see any specific requirement for a version of library. Then what dictates to link to 2.4 version libraries?

Sorry if this is theoretical but this would be highly beneficial to beginners like me. Please do comment for a suitable question title if the current one is not appropriate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your opencv2.4 libraries are located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` while the new opencv3 libraries are most likely located in /usr/local/lib. The linker is first looking in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` directory, and thus finding the opencv2.4 libs first. To fix this you can tell the linker to look in `/usr/local/lib` first by adding the following to your `~/.bashrc` file

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Reload the bashrc file in the terminal as follows (or simply close and re-open the terminal):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And update the library database:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

To check the order in which the linker will search for libraries, you can use the following:

```
ld -lopencv_core --verbose | grep attempt
```